# Node.js flash task bar icon?

Tags: node.js

I have been searching for a Node module that would allow my application to draw attention from the user by flashing [like this](https://news-cdn.softpedia.com/images/news2/how-to-change-the-number-of-taskbar-icon-flashes-in-windows-10-version-1709-519686-3.jpg). Is this possible using Node?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with electronjs

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.once('focus', () => win.flashFrame(false))
win.flashFrame(true)
```

[documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-taskbar#flash-frame)

Comment: Getting this: TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor